# remove span by class from $(this).html()

Tags: html, ajax

Basically my search returns search results in spans, then when one is clicked, a new span is added to another div with a select input and hidden input so all the selected features can be posted as an array.

My question is, `$(this).html()` now includes a span of class `alias_span`. Which I don't want to appear in the new span. How do I remove it before inserting the contents of the clicked span into the new span

```
$(".minisearch_res").live('click', function() { 

    // when a search result is clicked we disable the submit button, 
    // append a span to the left column with an id, 
    // a select input to select standard/optional and
    // a hidden field with the required information to save and something to 
    // show the user


    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    var html = "<span class= \"added_result_cont\" id=\"" + id + "_cont\">";
    html += "<select name='" + id + "_sel'>";
    html += "<option value=\"none\" selected=\"selected\"></option>";
    html += "<option value=\"std\">Standard</option>";
    html += "<option value=\"opt\" >Optional</option>";
    html += "</select>";
    html += "<span id= \"" + id + "\" class=\"added_result\">";
    html += "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"selectedfeat[]\" value=\"" + id + "\">";
    html += $(this).html() + "</span></span>";

    $('#div_apply_to').append(html);

    $(this).remove();
    $('#search_input').trigger('keyup');
    $("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

Update: here's the html of the span

```
<span class="minisearch_res" id="opt_1">Anti-Lock Brakes<br><span style="padding-left:20px" class="alias_span"><i>abs</i></span><br></span>
```

Comment: How about showing the HTML that you're attempting to describe?

Comment: be careful with this code. it doesn't look like you're validating anything

Comment: what should I be validating?

Comment: using user input to search a database. The span that is being clicked here is a sample search result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a tidy cross browser solution, which I'm very proud of :)

```
var temp = $(this);
temp.children('.alias_span').remove();
 $('#div_apply_to').append("...html..." + temp.html() + "...html...");
```

inspiration came from here:
[Remove element from Ajax Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290716/remove-element-from-ajax-response)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div></div>
```

Add it to the dom, then remove it.

```
var htm = (
    '<span class="foo">foo</span>' +
    '<span>bar</span>' +
    '<span>bar</span>' +
    '<span>bar</span>' +
    '<span>bar</span>'
);

var $el = $("div").append(htm);
console.log($el.html());
$el.find('.foo').remove();
console.log($el.html());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chovy/w2HdE/

Comment: is this removing the instance of .foo from just the html being handled? or all instances of .foo on the page?

Comment: this adds .foo to the div and then remvoes it later. Not sure why doesn't work in IE

Comment: after a bit of research, this explains why it doesn't work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585351/testing-for-console-log-statements-in-ie